# Is there a newline character in Anaconda Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Anyway. I was just wondering what \n is in Anaconda Python. When I input "\nabc" in the shell, it does not give me a new line. Instead, it outputs '\nabc'.

Comment: Check out [How to ask question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As far as I a aware, Anaconda Python is no different. I'm not sure what the problem is for you, can you post the code that you're trying to break?

Please also see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help pages. The title is good, but the body is severely lacking information.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try to add some useful information to help. Anyway, newbie here obviously. I was trying to input "\nabc" into the shell and out came '\nabc' and it did not create a new line.